# behat 3 with chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, behat

I want to run behat 3 with chrome but unable to run the --init
my behat.yml

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://someurl.com'
      javascript_session: selenium2
      selenium2:
        browser: chrome
      goutte: ~
```

my composer.json file is as following:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
    "behat/behat": "3.*@stable",
    "behat/mink": "1.6.*@stable",
    "behat/mink-extension": "@stable",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "@stable",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
    "peridot-php/webdriver-manager": "dev-master",
    "bossa/phpspec2-expect": "*"
  },
  "config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
  }
}
```

getting the following error

> [Behat\Testwork\ServiceContainer\Exception\ExtensionInitializationException]
>     `Behat\MinkExtension\Extension` extension file or class could not be located.

Comment: I fixed with followings.. thanks all for the help
behat.yml
-----
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: http://v6staging.academicapproach.com
      selenium2: ~
      browser_name: 'chrome'
  suites:
      defaults:
          contexts:
              - FeatureContext
              - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
---------------
composer:
{
    "require": {
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3"
    }
}
---------

Answer (score 0):

As it seems

> Behat\MinkExtension\Extension extension file or class could not be located.

You need to remove Extension from behat.yml
Replace *Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:* with *Behat\MinkExtension:*

After this it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your extensions block in the yml configurations file to something like this:

```
extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
        base_url: "http://www.your-web.com/"
        sessions:
            chrome_mac:
                selenium2:
                    browser: "chrome"
                    wd_host: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4444/wd/hub
                    capabilities:
                        platform: WINDOWS
                        browser: chrome
                        version: ""
                        extra_capabilities:
                            chromeOptions:
                                args:
                                    - "--start-maximized"
```

The "extra_capabilities section is optional. 
This should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

I use default chrome browser only, I think may work to you, cause I do this every in my project test.

```
default:
  autoload:
    '': %paths.base%/features/bootstrap
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: https://www.test your url.com
      default_session: selenium2
      files_path: features/Resources
      show_cmd: 'open %s'
      selenium2:
        browser: chrome
        wd_host: http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all i have fixed with the followings:
**Behat.yml**

```
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension:
      base_url: myURL.com
      selenium2: ~
      browser_name: 'chrome'
  suites:
      defaults:
          contexts:
              - FeatureContext
              - Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "behat/mink-extension": "^2.2",
        "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "^1.2",
        "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "^1.3"
    }
}
```

**Java in CLI**

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=geckodriver.exe seleneiumversionhere
```